# Merge loops with jQuery.extend: last value is always the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays of "hashes". I need to merge them together so the end result is another array of hashes, except the number of entries is the product of the two arrays.

```
    inhabitants = {}
    idx = 0
    for (i=0; i<persons.length; i++) {
        person = persons[i];
        for (j=0; j<houses.length; j++) {
            house = houses[j];
            console.log(house);
            inhabitants[idx] = $.extend(person,house);
            console.log(inhabitants[idx]);
            idx++;
        }
    }
```

What I end up with is a silly number of entries that depends on the ordering of the parameters in the $.extend() line. And the "house" entry that is added is ALWAYS THE LAST ENTRY IN THE ARRAY.

Clearly this $.extend() from jQuery is not doing what I expect. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but could you try `$.extend({}, person, house)` instead? You're currently overwriting `person`.

Comment: pimvdb, if the keys differ between the two hashes, won't the keys from house just be *added* to person? I will try what you say.

Comment: That's correct, but are you aware that you're basically assigning `person` to `inhabitants[idx]`? Note that the previously assigned object is also changed because there is only one `person` in the nested loop.

Comment: Please put that as the answer pimvdb, it worked!

Comment: Right, each person should be merged with each house.

Comment: But there is some difference between $.extend(person,house) and $.extend({},person,house) because only the second one does what I expect. The first one causes repetition of the same array entry over and over.

Comment: I see dzejkej, now I understand, thank you for explaining that. Since it's still the same person object, it's keeping those values. Makes sense now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.extend(a, b)` merges `b` into `a`, and returns `a`.

The return value you're using but it seems you were missing the fact that `a` is also being changed - you're currently assigning the same variable `person` to `inhabitants[idx]` each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really getting what you are trying to do, but anyway just a few hints. It's a good idea to place all the semicolons (here they're missing in the first and second line). Then I don't see why you are using an object instead of an array where you just have to push new items. Another thing is that in js it is faster to cache the lengths of the persons and houses collections. I will try to come up with code how I understood your task, maybe I'm getting it wrong:

```js
var inhabitants = [],
    idx = 0,
    personCount = persons.length,
    houseCount = houses.length,
    person = {},
    house = {},
    i = 0,
    j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    person = persons[i];
    for (j = 0; j < houseCount; j++) {
        house = houses[j];
        inhabitants.push($.extend({}, person, house);
    }
}
```

So to me it seems like a database join between the two tables persons and houses. Is this what you meant?