# private variable in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, global-variables, private

I'm making a jQuery plugin in which one each elements should have their own variables. I believed the correct way to do so was:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>test 1</div>
<div>test 2</div>
<script language="javascript">
$.fn.menu = function(options) {
    var defaults = {i : 0};
    this.each(function(){
        var parameters = $.extend(defaults, options); 
        $(this).on("click", function(event){parameters.i++;alert(parameters.i);});
    });
};
$("div").menu();
</script>
```

but it doesn't work: the parameters object is global and so shared between all elements for which the plugin is called.

What's wrong in this example?

Comment: It isn't global but you are facing closure issue...

Comment: Why do you want to use a closure here? It's not a loop, and there's nothing to do with the answered question you link ! Moreover, the goal is to show the last value of i... it's the opposite of what a closure is means to do.

Comment: `each` is looping method

Comment: your point. However, parameters is defined in the each(). Couldyou please remove the "already answrred elsewhere" ? the question is different and the answer given doesn't answer to this one.

Comment: @Comode You are correct, your issue is regarding you are extending same object, use: `var parameters = $.extend({}, defaults, options);`

Comment: Maybe more relevant dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332458/merge-loops-with-jquery-extend-last-value-is-always-the-same

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `var parameters = $.extend(defaults, options);`, `parameters` is reference to (extended) `defaults` object.

> Keep in mind that the target object (first argument) will be modified,
>   and will also be returned from $.extend().

You need to create a new object reference, passing empty one to jQuery `extend()` method:

```
var parameters = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var parameters = $.extend(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaults)), options);
```